# html form not submitting "select" options to google sheets

Tags: html, forms, google-apps-script

Hello stackoverflow community,
I am making a html form that sends data to my google sheets. All my 'input' options submit to google sheets, however my 'select' options are left blank. I included my html code, is there a way to include dropdown options in my form and have them submit to google sheets? Or am I stuck with just using the 'input' element?

Thanks so much in advanced!

```
<form 
  method="POST" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx1mOgHyY4XVaDE3Fsk3_NcdqQcoqoJniOC3TxJaVcvwVM28Mlhgqv_dRSjICB-bdw/exec"
>
  <input name="Name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
  <input name="Email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
  <input name="Phone number" type="number" placeholder="Phone number" required>
  <select name="Contact" placeholder="Contact method" required>
      <optgroup label="Contact method" required>
          <option value>Call</option>
          <option value>Text</option>
          <option value>Email</option></select>
  <select name="Device" type="text" placeholder="Device type" required>
      <optgroup label="Device type">
          <option value>Windows</option>
          <option value>Mac</option>
          <option value="13">Chromebook</option>
          <option value>Other Device</option>
      </optgroup> </select>
  <select name="Repair" placeholder="Email" required>
      <optgroup label="Repair type">
          <option value="undefined">Cracked screen</option>
          <option value="12">Frame damage</option>
          <option value selected>Cleaning &amp; repaste</option>
          <option value>Software issues</option>
          <option value="13">Battery replacement</option>
          <option value>Won&#39;t charge</option>
          <option value="14">other</option>
      </optgroup>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

I created a html form that sends data to google sheets, however not all responses will submit to my google sheets. All help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To ensure that your dropdown options from the  elements submit to Google Sheets, you need to provide a value attribute for each  tag. Currently, your  tags only have the value attribute without any values specified.
For example, you can update your code as follows:**

```html
<form 
  method="POST" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx1mOgHyY4XVaDE3Fsk3_NcdqQcoqoJniOC3TxJaVcvwVM28Mlhgqv_dRSjICB-bdw/exec"
>
  <input name="Name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
  <input name="Email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
  <input name="Phone number" type="number" placeholder="Phone number" required>
  <select name="Contact" required>
    <optgroup label="Contact method">
      <option value="Call">Call</option>
      <option value="Text">Text</option>
      <option value="Email">Email</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
  <select name="Device" required>
    <optgroup label="Device type">
      <option value="Windows">Windows</option>
      <option value="Mac">Mac</option>
      <option value="Chromebook">Chromebook</option>
      <option value="Other Device">Other Device</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
  <select name="Repair" required>
    <optgroup label="Repair type">
      <option value="Cracked screen">Cracked screen</option>
      <option value="Frame damage">Frame damage</option>
      <option value="Cleaning &amp; repaste">Cleaning &amp; repaste</option>
      <option value="Software issues">Software issues</option>
      <option value="Battery replacement">Battery replacement</option>
      <option value="Won't charge">Won't charge</option>
      <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

**In this updated code, each  tag now has a specified value attribute that corresponds to the selected option.**

Comment: Thanks so much! that totally fixed my issue. One last question, how can I make it so on form submit it redirects instead of saying "success"?